# How to tell if I successfully use RAID

Tags: server, raid

I configured RAID on our server and I installed Ubuntu 16.04. I want to know if I successfully use the RAID setup . How do I check this on our server ?

This is result of lsblk

```
Name    Maj:min     RM          SIZE        RO      TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sda     8:0         0           465.8G      0       disk
 |
 |--sda1 8:1        0           465.9G      0       part/
 |--sda2 8:2        0               1k      0       part/
 |--sda5 8:5        0             3.9G      0       part/[swap] 

 sdb    8:16        0           465.8G      0       disk
 sdc    8:32        0           465.8G      0       disk
 sdd    8:48        0           465.8G      0       disk
```

Comment: What kind of server ? :)

Comment: is that a hardware or software (i.e. using mdadm) raid?

Comment: Can you boot into Ubuntu? Edit your post to include the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: is that command lsblk ? sorry I am new to ubuntu..okay I will

Comment: @muru I paste the result

Comment: @jemz If you're using RAID, it doesn't look like the RAID devices have been activated. Output with RAID activated looks like http://paste.ubuntu.com/17352640/ (note the `md` devices)

Comment: how to activate the raid devices ?

Answer (score 1):

To check **Software RAID** status, run following command:

```
sudo cat /proc/mdstat
```

It will provide you out with three possible values as follows:

```
root@tmp:~$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] 
116414912 blocks [2/1] [_U] 
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1] 
803136 blocks [2/2] [UU] 
unused devices: <none>
```

Personalities on this machine are *"raid1"* which means this machine is set-up to use raid devices configured in a raid1 configuration.

Here,

**[UU]** indicates a healthy RAID partition.

**[_U]** or

**[U_]** indicates a failed partition. 
You can read more on this at [Installation/SoftwareRAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID)

To check **Hardware RAID** status,

```
sudo aptitude install mpt-status       
sudo modprobe mptctl                --Load the *mptctl* kernel module
sudo mpt-status -p                  --Find the SCSI ID for your disk array
```

To get RAID status report:

```
sudo mpt-status -i 2                --“2” is the SCSI ID from above step
```

Comment: I tried the command but the personalities is linear [raid1][raid2][raid3] [raid5],i forgot the actual raid number but that is what it looks like

Answer (score 0):

Well it's relatively simple, let's say you have 10TB storage if you configured one volume in raid 10 you would have around 5TB left. When you come to install Ubuntu you should see the volume you created with 5TB available to use.

Comment: without knowing the raid type and other parameters its somehow unsafe to "just" calculate from my point of view

Comment: I have 4disk 500gb size  in our server, I tried df-h I see /dev/sda1 size is 455G.

Comment: Well he could shut down his server and go into the intleigent provisioning screen and see what is configured but it's sometimes not feasible to shut down a server, so that's why I've suggested calculated but I'll edit my answer